# Pairwise Euclidean distance with pandas ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, euclidean-distance

I start with a dictionary, which is the way my data was already formatted:

```
import pandas as pd
dict2 = {'A': {'a':1.0, 'b':2.0, 'd':4.0}, 'B':{'a':2.0, 'c':2.0, 'd':5.0}, 
'C':{'b':1.0,'c':2.0, 'd':4.0}}
```

I then convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
print(df)
     A    B    C
a  1.0  2.0  NaN
b  2.0  NaN  1.0
c  NaN  2.0  2.0
d  4.0  5.0  4.0
```

Of course, I can get the difference one at a time by doing this:

```
df['A'] - df['B']
Out[643]: 
a   -1.0
b    NaN
c    NaN
d   -1.0
dtype: float64
```

I figured out how to loop through and calculate A-A, A-B, A-C:

```
for column in df:
print(df['A'] - df[column])

a    0.0
b    0.0
c    NaN
d    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
a   -1.0
b    NaN
c    NaN
d   -1.0
dtype: float64
a    NaN
b    1.0
c    NaN
d    0.0
dtype: float64
```

What I would like to do is iterate through the columns so as to calculate |A-B|, |A-C|,  and |B-C| and store the results in another dictionary.

I want to do this so as to calculate the Euclidean distance between all combinations of columns later on. If there is an easier way to do this I would like to see it as well. Thank you.

Comment: There are faster ways of computing pairwise euclidean distance. How do you want NaNs to be handled?

Comment: NaNs  are to be skipped over, @coldspeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting to compute vectorised Euclidean distance (L2-norm), ignoring NaNs using `np.nansum`.

```
i = df.values.T
j = np.nansum((i - i[:, None]) ** 2, axis=2) ** .5
```

If you want a DataFrame representing a distance matrix, here's what that would look like:

```
df = (lambda v, c: pd.DataFrame(v, c, c))(j, df.columns)
df
          A         B    C
A  0.000000  1.414214  1.0
B  1.414214  0.000000  1.0
C  1.000000  1.000000  0.0
```

`df[i, j]` represents the distance between the i<sup>th</sup> and j<sup>th</sup> column in the original DataFrame.

Comment: That did work very well, actually. So how does this work? The first line creates an array of the data, and the second one does the calculation. Could you help me understand the line that creates the new dataframe? Thank you

Comment: @Jabernet I don't like typing a lot, nor do I like repeating myself, so I represent `pd.DataFrame(j, df.columns, df.columns)` as `(lambda v, c: pd.DataFrame(v, c, c))(j, df.columns)`. I set the index and columns of the result to be the columns in the original dataframe.

Comment: @Jabernet By the way, if you want the L2 NORM, then you will have to `j = np.nansum((i - i[:, None]) ** 2, axis=2) ** .5` to take the sqrt of the result. I've just given you the L2, without the sqrt.

Comment: Okay yes, I see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `code` below iterates through columns to calculate the difference.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'a':1.0, 'b':2.0, 'd':4.0}, 'B':{'a':2.0, 'c':2.0, 'd':5.0},'C':{'b':1.0,'c':2.0, 'd':4.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

# Calculate difference
clist = df.columns
for i in range (0,len(clist)-1):
    for j in range (1,len(clist)):
        if (clist[i] != clist[j]):
            var = clist[i] + '-' + clist[j]
            df[var] = abs(df[clist[i]] - df[clist[j]]) # optional
            df2[var] = abs(df[clist[i]] - df[clist[j]]) # optional
```

**Output in same dataframe**

```
df.head()
```

[image]

**Output in a new dataframe**

```
df2.head()
```

[image]

Comment: Why is "iterates" and "columns" accentuated with code font?

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the sentence. I am new to Stackoverflow posting and still learning the proper syntax for write-up. There I was trying to highlight those two words.