# How to compute distance from elements of an array in python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a numpy array where each element is a position, like this :

```
array([[1, 1, 0. ],
       [2 , 2, 0. ],
       [3 , 3, 1 ]])
```

And I want to compute the distance between each element. So here, the expected output is :

```
[0, 1.414213, 1.732050]
```

The distance is calculated as it follows : 
For the first element it is 0 because ther isn't any element before. For the second it is `sqrt((2 - 1)**2 + (2 - 1)**2 + (0 - 0)**2))` and so on

However, there is a lot of elements (around some thousands), and this operation is repeated multiple times. So I need a way to execute this very fast.

I was wondering if there is a library (or even better a numpy function) that could solve my problem. I used `cdist` from scipy.spatial.distance before, but it doesn't work anymore (I have problems with scipy dependencies), so I'm searching for another way.

Comment: How did you arrive at the output? Look into Scipy's pdist.

Comment: For the first element it is 0 because ther isn't any element before. For the second it is `sqrt((2 - 1)**2 + (2 - 1)**2 + (0 - 0)**2))` and so on

Comment: I can't use scipy.spatial as I said. It's a problem about my python configuration, I've made a post about that an hour ago, but I haven't found a way to make it work

Comment: This should solve/get you closer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030458/. For ext. sources - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure numpy solution. `a` is your input vector array. You first create the distances component wise, then square them, then sum them over each row, and then get the sqrt of each of those sums.

```
np.sqrt(np.sum((a[1:] - a[:-1])**2, axis=1))
```

> array([ 1.41421356,  1.73205081])