# Vectorized euclidean distance along an axis of a 3D array - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

How can a function that operates on 2D arrays (cdist) be applied along an axis of a 3D array ?

I tried with `numpy.apply_along_axis` , but I need to operate on 2D arrays, not 1D. I obtained the result I need by iterating along one axis, but I would prefer it vectorized if possible:

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(600).reshape(10, 20, 3)
distances = np.array([spatial.distance.cdist(a[i,:,:], a[i,:,:]) for i in range(a.shape[0])])
```

Comment: Do You have a coordinate system with 10x20 points? And do You now want to compute the distance of these points along the dimension of N=20? (by any chance :D )

Comment: Yup, you got met :D

Comment: glad the answer from Divakar fit Your purporse then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030534/), we can solve it in a vectorized manner. So, following the  [`wiki contents`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method) from [`eucl_dist`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist)  package  (disclaimer: I am its author), we could leverage `matrix-multiplication` and some [`NumPy specific implementations`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#methodology), like so -

```
a_s = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',a,a)
sq_dists = a_s[...,None]+a_s[...,None,:]-2*np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',a,a)
dists = np.sqrt(sq_dists)
```

Alternative(s) :

- We can use `np.matmul/@-operator on Python3.x` to replace the matrix-multiplication part. Hence, `np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',a,a)` could be replaced by `np.matmul(a,a.transpose(0,2,1))`.

Comment: That did it, thank you very much ! I'd never have guessed it by myself.